# How do "componentWillUnmount" work with clearinterval?

Tags: reactjs

Why do they use `componentWillUnmount` to `clearInterval` here ?

```
componentWillUnmount() {
   clearInterval(this.timerID);
   console.log("here");  //nothing happens
}
```

[in this example at the official docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

Why do they use it since this method doesn't get called in this cycle and thus the clearInterval won't execute every second ? Isn't the idea behind this to clear the interval every second since every second there is a new interval happening ? or I am misunderstanding ?

Comment: Was my answer helpful? If so, feel free to vote it up and if it resolved your question click on the checkmark. You'll get a few rep points, as well. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When the component unMounts and is removed from the DOM we don't want the this.tick() to run anymore. `componentWillUnmount` is meant to eliminate the interval that was set earlier when it mounted:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.timerID = setInterval(
      () => this.tick(),
      1000
    );
  }
```

`componentWillUnmount` and `componentDidMount` like most of the lifecycle methods are to deal with stuff outside of what React directly manages but stuff that still happens as part of your component.

Comment: I get this, what I don't understand is when the component unmounts ? does it unmount every second then ? if so then why doesn't it clear the interval and logs the line after it ?

Comment: `componentWillUnmount` only runs when the component is going away (unmounting), so `this.tick()` runs every 1000ms until `componentWillUnmount` removes it. Then the ticking stops. The component in the example starts ticking when it's mounted (appears) and stops ticking when it is unmounted (goes away). Keep in mind that the `clearInterval` is INSIDE `componentWillUnmount`. It runs when `componentWillUnmount` runs, not the other way around.

Comment: So the simple answer: No. It only runs once, when the component is going away.