# ComponentWillUnmount() doesn't clear interval

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a countdown timer that should invoke a method once it turns to 0. Then, a new page is rendered and the countdown should reset and start again. It works as intended until the component unmounts. The method `timeNext()` gets then called every second because the interval doesn't stop anymore.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Countdown extends Component {

    state = {
        timer: this.props.timer
    }

    decrementTimeRemaining = () => {
        if (this.state.timer > 0) {
            this.setState({
                timer: this.state.timer - 1
            });
        } else {
            clearInterval(this.timerFunction);

            this.props.timeNext();
            this.setState({ timer: this.props.timer });
            this.decrement();
        }
    };

    decrement() {
        this.timerFunction = setInterval(() => {
            this.decrementTimeRemaining();
        }, 1000);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.decrement()
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        console.log("unmounted")
        clearInterval(this.timerFunction);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>{this.state.timer} </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Countdown;
```

I suspect it somewhere causes an infinite loop. I thought clearing the interval in `componentWillUnmount()` would work, but apparently there is a mistake. There seems to be an interval running even when the component gets unmounted and I don't know how to stop it.

Comment: I don't see where this.timerFunction is defined, other than in the function body of decrement, and because decrement isn't declared as a lambda, has it's own this scope. I'm going to guess that is your problem. If decrement were declared like decrementTimeRemaining, it might work because this.timerFunction would be bound to the Countdown class's scope.

Comment: Doesn't solve it unfortunately.

Comment: Instead of calling decrement() inside of your timer function you should reset this.state.timer back to a default value. That call to decrement() inside of your timer function is a race condition at the very least.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include all the relevant code snippets? We can't know what the problem is if you don't show us the functions and props that are being passed in.

Comment: **Hi! Possibly you can find your answer here** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43508744/how-do-componentwillunmount-work-with-clearinterval][1]

Comment: @RobB The props and functions won't give you any relevant new information. If I delete the decrement() method in decrementTimeRemaining() it works fine, but the countdown doesn't restart, it just happens once. I have a feeling that maybe there is always one new interval created that I don't clear, causing the repeated function call.  I just don't know how I can restart the timer after it counts to zero.

Comment: @TimothyJannace But I do reset the timer to a default value when it runs to zero. The problem is starting it again without causing a loop.

Comment: @LeartMorina Hi, well this is what I've already done.

Comment: @fallc I'll make a post of what I mean.

Comment: I notice you have `this.setState({ timer: this.props.timer }); this.decrement();`. Since `decrement()` relies on the state, you should call it in `setState`'s callback instead, like this: `this.setState({ timer: this.props.timer}, () => this.decrement());`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've over-complicated your decrementTimeRemaining function. I would refactor the function like this:

```
decrementTimeRemaining = () => {
    if (this.state.timer > 0) {
        this.setState({
            timer: this.state.timer - 1
        });
    } else {
        this.setState({ timer: this.props.timer });
    }
};
```

Now componentWillUnmount is the only place that clearInterval is called and componentDidMount is the only place that the interval is started.

Comment: Thanks, you're the man! I think I get it, you don't need to clear the interval, you just let it roll with a new value. I thought I have to clear the interval and start a new one when it hits zero.